# sycndb table already exists

Tags: django

History: I have been following "*The Definitive Guide to Django - 2nd Edition"* to Chapter 6, which means so far I have run `syncdb` successfully once.

**Solution:**

```
   1) As unix super user deleted ../mysql/data/books. 
   2) Added "II" to publisher and author tables in the models.py.
```

**Environment:**

```
   solaris 5.10, django-1.2.4, mysql-5.5.8, python-2.4.6
```

**Question:**

```
   What file must I Delete/Modify the next time I want to start from scratch? 
   (ie re-run syncdb for the first time)
```

Thanks,

emilio

Comment: Why wouldn't you delete the entire database?

Answer (score 0):

[manage.py flush](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#flush) might be enough for you

For development and for learning it is more convenient to use sqlite database. Then you could simply delete one file.

If you need to delete mysql database, better do this with [mysql command line tool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html) and do not mess with mysql files. You can drop database like this:

```
mysql -u root -p

mysql> drop database dbname
```